# Use JS Proxy to get nested form element

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I want to make accessing my form elements easier in JS. Forms have the property 'elements' that gives you access to all the DOM inputs. This allows to get elements either by their position or their DOM name.

This becomes cumbersome however when using arrays in the input name:

```
<input name='shipping[address][city]' />
const shippingCity = form.elements['shipping[address][city]'];
```

It would be much nicer to access it with dot notation:

```
const inputs = new Proxy(form.elements, {
  get(target, handler) { 
    ...
  }
}
const shippingCity = inputs.shipping.address.city;
```

I'm guessing theres a way to do this with JS proxies. I've found examples on how to access nested data in an object but this needs to build the string from the properties instead, then return the DOM at the top level proxy. I'm guessing this would take 2 seperate proxy handlers.

TLDR: Turn X -> Y

```
inputs.shipping.address.city -> form.elements['shipping[address][city]']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer you a solution which works like this, but I warn you it's overwhelmingly hacky. It has to wrap every object property with a proxy, and I wouldn't trust it not to create property name collisions which would be horrible to debug.

```js
const subAccessor = (obj, base, path) => new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (target, prop) => {
        const newPath = `${path}[${prop}]`;
        const obj = base[newPath];
        if (target[prop]) return target[prop];
        return subAccessor(obj || {}, base, newPath);
    }
});

const inputs = new Proxy(form.elements, {
    get: (target, prop) => {
        return subAccessor(target[prop] || {}, target, prop);
    }
});
```

That's code is a truly awful solution, though, so I *strongly* recommend that you instead use a simple helper function such as

```js
// usage: `getInput('shipping.address.city')`
const getInput = path => form.elements[
    path.split('.')
    .map((part, i) => i > 0 ? `[${part}]` : part)
    .join('')
];
```